# Microservices and oauth architecture

Tags: oauth, architecture, microservices

I'm learning microservice architecture and I have some questions.

Lets imagine arhitecture like this:
We have simple html pages (example.com): main page, information for developers, login, sign up, etc. Login page (example.com/login) contains a lot of oauth buttons (e.g. facebook, google+, twitter, etc). All of them have client_id, state (generates every request and saves in session) and redirect_url. So, the redirect_url points to another microservice (auth.example.com/oauth?code=...&state=...). Then, I change the code to a token, send request like get_user_info and save it in db (aka registration or update user). After than I generate a JWT token to call my API and return the token to user with redurect to dashboard.example.com. On this page user will use my API (api.example.com) with the JWT token.

Thus, we have 3 microservice: main site (contains info and login) - example.com, auth server (authorize and authentication) - auth.example.com and API service - api.example.com

And questions:
1. How I can check the state when oauth provider redirect it from example.com (this we store the state in session) to auth.example.com? I think use rebbitMQ, it ok?
2. Can I put JWT token in body and send response with HTTP 302 redirect (redirect to dash.boardexample.com)?

I'll be glad to hear your opinions and your advice!

Thanks,
Dima.